# create c# installer - ask for shortcut parameters

Tags: c#, console-application, nsis, advanced-installer

Is it possible to create an installer for a simple .exe (console application) which is asking for parameters to pass to the shortcut?

My application needs to have "source path" and "destination path" and a 3rd optional parameter...

I really don't know what I have to look for in Google (english words).

Also, I need to place this shortcut in the Startup, is this possible?

I've took a look at nsis and advanced installer and they seem to not allow that option.

**EDIT**

What I want is, during the install, ask a question to the user for what are the arguments. Depending on which user, the arguments will be differents.

I'm also looking for something free because I will probably never use it again...

Comment: Yes, use the Visual Studio Installer project.

Comment: Inno Setup is the best free setup software I have found thus far: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php also, for passing parameters to the application just use args[] in the program.cs (for winform) and just the main for a console app

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dialogs in NSIS by using the [nsDialogs plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html):

```
OutFile "mysetup.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"

Page Custom CustomShortcutPageCreate CustomShortcutLeave
Page InstFiles

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var ShortcutParameter

Function CustomShortcutPageCreate
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 10u 100% 12u "Please enter the shortcut parameter"
    Pop $0
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 30u 100% 12u ""
    Pop $9
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function CustomShortcutLeave
    ${NSD_GetText} $9 $ShortcutParameter
FunctionEnd

Section
    SetOutPath $InstDir
    File MyApp.exe
SectionEnd

Section
    CreateDirectory "$SMStartup" ; Make sure the folder exists just in case the user has "cleaned" their start menu
    CreateShortcut "$SMStartup\MyApp.lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe" $ShortcutParameter
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using C# and Microsoft Visual Studio.
In that case you can use both NSIS and Inno Setup for creating your installer.

Use any Visual Studio version with the **Visual & Installer** extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e57fe9a-ae5d-4740-a1c3-7a8e278e105b)

NSIS example mentioned above will work perfectly in it (also similar Inno Setup code).

Answer (score -1):

With the [Simple project type from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), which is free forever, you can create a [shortcut with custom arguments](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html#shortcuts) in 2 minutes.

Just set the arguments desired in the field **Arguments** visible in the dialog editing the shortcut properties, as per below:

[image]

I don't understand how you want to customize the third parameter. Can you give more details, an example?

In the **Arguments** field you can set properties like this **[MY_CUSTOM_ARG]** and have the value of the property resolve to a custom value at install time (of course, before the shortcuts are installed).

**EDIT** With the free/Simple edition of Advanced Installer you cannot customize the dialogs, you can only use one of the predefined ones, available in Dialogs page.

The Dialogs Editor is available as a feature of the commercial Enterprise edition for Advanced Installer.

A free open source alternative is to use Wix Toolset, however, the learning curve can be steep if you never worked with it.

Comment: What I want is, during the install, ask a question to the user for what are the arguments. Depending on which user, the arguments will be differents.